# Mac Catalyst: Horizontal Mouse scroll with click drag

Tags: macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

Preparing an iPad App for native MacOS experience using Mac Catalyst (and AppKit when needed) and using SwiftUI.

We observe that Horizontal Scroll is tricky using a Mouse! Most users have the habit of click+drag to scroll horizontally. This does not seem to be default behavior on ScrollView.

Strange: Same App when compiled on "Mac (Designed for iPad)" [aka Silicon only] scrolls horizontally with click drag. But not if compiled with Mac Catalyst.

**Question**: How can we enable general click-drag for horizontal scrolling using SwiftUI on Mac Catalyst? I wouldn't mind using specific AppKit framework if needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this:

Adding `UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents` as YES to the App's plist will enable the default behavior.

Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationsupportsindirectinputevents